# XML commet for return collection of type T

Tags: c#, xml-comments, generic-collections

I would like specify in XML comments that method return collection of `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`.

What is  correct format for XML tag `<returns/>`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extensions methods for class <see cref="System.IO.DirectoryInfo"/>
/// </summary>
public static class DirectoryInfoExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Load files from folder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dir">Folder</param>
    /// <param name="searchOption">search options</param>
    /// <param name="extensions">types of files</param>
    /// <returns>Collection of <see cref="IEnumerable{FileInfo}"/></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> ByExtensions(this DirectoryInfo dir,
        SearchOption searchOption, params string[] extensions)
    {
    }
```

Comment: @Rex M: I don’t understand why is my question marked as duplicate because method doesn’t return generic IEnumerable<T> but IEnumerable<FileInfo>. My problem is that I don’t know how specify FileInfo in XML comment. Thank

Comment: the information and MSDN links in the various answers does address this. I'll summarize: What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense, when considering what xmldocs are for. There is no such type as `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`. So you want to use "IEnumerable{T}" (which is a real type) and add `<see cref="System.IO.FileInfo" />` to essentially add a helper entry.

Comment: Your returns documentation should read something like "A collection of <see cref="FileInfo"/> instances describing [what]". You don't need to link to `IEnumerable<T>`.